# tool for custom web based reporting from your db?

Tags: database, graphics, reporting

I am looking for online reporting tool that I can design my own reports .

reports should be totally custom and based on my own schema so I would like to define queries and see them on a dashboard or something like that

Comment: Where is the data for these reports coming from?

Comment: on my own database, on a remote server... I can reach and deploy the applications and modify some files, in short on my own VPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say which kind of database you're using so here are a few to consider:-

- http://www.dbfacephp.com/mockup
- http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear/designer
- http://devtools.korzh.com/query-builder-component/
- http://mydbr.com/
- http://www.freereporting.com/
- http://datavision.sourceforge.net/
- http://reportman.sourceforge.net/

Comment: oh cool it was mysql  and I can install php ... I will check them cheers